# Javascript sort custom comparator function - sorting a sorted array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects of the following form:

```
arr[0] = { 'item1' : 1234, 'item2' : 'a string' };
```

I sort it first by `'item1'` which is straightforward. Now i want to sort `arr` (which is sorted by `'item1'`) again but this time by `'item2'` but only for the elements where `'item1'` is the same. The final array would look like:

```
arr = [
  { 'item1' : 1234, 'item2' : 'apple' },
  { 'item1' : 1234, 'item2' : 'banana' },
  { 'item1' : 1234, 'item2' : 'custard' },
  { 'item1' : 2156, 'item2' : 'melon' },
  { 'item1' : 4345, 'item2' : 'asparagus' } 
];
```

I tried to write a sorting function for the second case like so:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b){
  if(a.item1 === b.item1){
    return a.item2 > b.item2 ? 1 : a.item2 < b.item2 : -1 : 0;
  }
});
```

I could combine the two sorts in one function to get the final sorted array but there will be cases where I'll have to sort by just `'item1'` or just `'item2'`.

Comment: If you managed to sort by item1, item2, and both of them, then what are you asking exactly?

Comment: So its like writing a decorator pattern where i say "new sortByItem2( new sortByItem1(arr))". I also want to use it like sortByItem1(arr) or sortByItem2(arr) or "new sortByItem1( new sortByItem2(arr))"

Answer (score 49):

You can have four different comparison functions - one sorting by item1, one by item2, one by item1 then item2 and one by item2 then item1.

E.g.:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b){
  if(a.item1 == b.item1){
    return a.item2 > b.item2 ? 1 : a.item2 < b.item2 ? -1 : 0;
  }

  return a.item1 > b.item1 ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Answer (score 8):

I hit the same question lately. Came with a similar solution than langpavel, but I prefer to split the thing in two. First a chained comparator helper that will allows multiple sort rule, each applied in order as a tie-breaker in case of equality:

```
    type Comparator<T> = (a: T, b: T) => number; // -1 | 0 | 1

    /**
     * Allow to chain multiple comparators, each one called to break equality from the previous one.
     */
    function chainedComparator<T>(...comparators: Comparator<T>[]): Comparator<T> {
        return (a: T, b: T) => {
            let order = 0;
            let i = 0;
    
            while (!order && comparators[i]) {
                order = comparators[i++](a, b);
            }
    
            return order;
        };
    }
```

I like it, because it takes and return sort comparator. So if you have a collection of other comparators, they are easy to use.

Then you can simplify a bit your life with an additional helper. This one return a sort comparator based on the result of the passed lambda over each items.

```
    type Comparable = string | number;

    /**
     * Returns a comparator which use an evaluationFunc on each item for comparison
     */
    function lambdaComparator<T>(evaluationFunc: ((item: T) => Comparable), reversed = false): Comparator<T> {
        return (a: T, b: T) => {
            const valA = evaluationFunc(a);
            const valB = evaluationFunc(b);
            let order = 0;
    
            if (valA < valB) {
                order = -1;
            } else if (valA > valB) {
                order = 1;
            }
            return reversed ? -order : order;
        };
    }
```

`reversed` here is not required to answer the question, but will allow to reverse the order easily.

To answer the question specifically, using our two comparators:

```
    arr.sort(chainedComparator(
        lambdaComparator(a => a.item1),
        lambdaComparator(a => a.item2.toLowerCase()) // "banana" before "Melon"
    ));
```

Because the original question was in pure JavaScript, precision: If you're not accustomed to TypeScript, you can get normal JavaScript just by removing the typing `<T>`, `: T`, `: ((item: T) => Comparable)` everywhere and the two `type` lines out.

Comment: `scoreA` should be `valA` in the lambdaComparator, `B` alike.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this helper in TypeScript:

```
// Source
type ComparatorSelector<T> = (value: T, other: T) => number | string | null;

export function createComparator<T>(...selectors: ComparatorSelector<T>[]) {
  return (a: T, b: T) => {
    for (const selector of selectors) {
      const valA = selector(a, b);
      if (valA === null) continue;
      const valB = selector(b, a);
      if (valB === null || valA == valB) continue;
      if (valA > valB) return 1;
      if (valA < valB) return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  };
}
```

---

```
// Usage:
const candidates: any[] = [];
// ...
candidates.sort(createComparator(
  (x) => x.ambiguous,
  (_, y) => y.refCount, // DESC
  (x) => x.name.length,
  (x) => x.name,
));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just import [type-comparator](https://github.com/lightness/type-comparator) with npm and then use [queue](https://github.com/lightness/type-comparator#function-queuecomparators) to do the chaining:

```
const comparator = queue([
    map(x => x.item1, asc),
    map(x => x.item2, asc)
]);
arr.sort(comparator);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or as simple oneliner for first and second priority sort, you can expand it further as you wish, just replace the 0 with another comparison chain. Switch **<** and **>** or **-1** and **1** for the reversed order.

```
someArray.sort(function(a,b) {
  return a.item1 > b.item1 ? 1 : a.item1 < b.item1 ? -1 : a.item2 > b.item2 ? 1 : a.item2 < b.item2 ? -1 : 0;
});
```