# array sorting follow by custom sequence in java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

How to sort an array follow by this sequence sm,s,m,l,xl.
For example,
I have an array like var a = [xl,sm,s,m] then i want to rearrange array to sm,s,m,xl

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157590/javascript-sort-custom-comparator-function-sorting-a-sorted-array

Comment: Please provide full example with expected result ?

Comment: what is the logic behind this new re-arrangement?

Comment: what is `sm`? a size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an object with the values of the strings and their position for sorting.

```js
var array = ['xl', 'sm', 's', 'm'],
    order = { sm: 1, s: 2, m: 3, xl: 4 };

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return order[a] - order[b];
});


console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont sure I understand what you want but I think you want something like below:

```
var sortGuide = ["sm", "s", "m", "xl"];
var a = ["xl", "sm", "s", "m"];
a.sort((it1, it2) => sortGuide.indexOf(it1) - sortGuide.indexOf(it2));
console.log(a);
```