# Is there a way to sort result body to make it more readable not sure where to start

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots

Is there a way to sort the results in the body? either import into googlesheets or just JS to make it organized and readable

RequestCode:

```
request('https://cb-live.synapse-games.com/api.php?message=getUserAccount&user_id=user&password=password', function (error, response, body) {
  console.error('error:', error); 
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); 
  console.log('body:', body); 
});
```

Im trying to organize:
by:
user_id
name

"faction":{"faction_id":"250803","leader_id":"20250028","name":"Banjos Elite","num_members":"50","inactive":"0","message":"Check guild forums for chat!","total_rating":800,"recruitment_status":"1","min_rating":"16","guild_icon":"133","mmr":"79288","last_update_time":"1653763086","siege_mmr":"7019","active_members":50,"max_members":50,"members":[{"user_id":"20250028","name":"zeKe586","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"4001","last_update_time":"1653762200","trophy_data":[{"asset_prefab":{"asset":"badge_1000","bundle_id":"48"},"label":"927"}],"member_role":10,"online":2},{"user_id":"2395363","name":"Jaykay","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"3001","last_update_time":"1653762427","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"5","online":2},{"user_id":"6832390","name":"Prince7","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"1005","last_update_time":"1653762392","trophy_data":[{"asset_prefab":{"asset":"badge_1000","bundle_id":"48"},"label":"649"}],"member_role":"5","online":2},{"user_id":"22065595","name":"Doggie22","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"1004","last_update_time":"1653762314","trophy_data":[{"asset_prefab":{"asset":"badge_1000","bundle_id":"48"},"label":"617"}],"member_role":"5","online":2},{"user_id":"14820228","name":"SternTheGern","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"3003","last_update_time":"1653747150","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"5","online":1},{"user_id":"8077447","name":"bossjon","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"5019","last_update_time":"1653744096","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"5","online":1},{"user_id":"20204539","name":"Daniele","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"1004","last_update_time":"1653741744","trophy_data":[{"asset_prefab":{"asset":"badge_1000","bundle_id":"48"},"label":"882"}],"member_role":"5","online":1},{"user_id":"13188108","name":"bosschevy62","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"4002","last_update_time":"1653719248","trophy_data":[{"asset_prefab":{"asset":"badge_1000","bundle_id":"48"},"label":"296"}],"member_role":"5","online":1},{"user_id":"21924152","name":"JamesH4046","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"4004","last_update_time":"1653718467","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"5","online":1},{"user_id":"19566579","name":"Pablo-first","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"3003","last_update_time":"1653763085","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":2},{"user_id":"9731386","name":"Wolftorn56","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"3004","last_update_time":"1653763082","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":2},{"user_id":"20006906","name":"pablo1","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"3003","last_update_time":"1653763055","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":2},{"user_id":"8258667","name":"BamaSlama","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"5019","last_update_time":"1653763045","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":2},{"user_id":"3418286","name":"btrswt","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"3005","last_update_time":"1653762856","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":2},{"user_id":"4357132","name":"GeorgeS929","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"3003","last_update_time":"1653762662","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":2},{"user_id":"2948152","name":"ZombieAtreus","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"1004","last_update_time":"1653762588","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":2},{"user_id":"13281217","name":"bennie","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"4002","last_update_time":"1653762555","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":2},{"user_id":"22387597","name":"NinjaBeast","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"1004","last_update_time":"1653762369","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":2},{"user_id":"19119727","name":"StarSunDust","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"1004","last_update_time":"1653762363","trophy_data":[{"asset_prefab":{"asset":"badge_1000","bundle_id":"48"},"label":"457"}],"member_role":"0","online":2},{"user_id":"8300737","name":"MrJokerOG","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"3004","last_update_time":"1653762289","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":2},{"user_id":"4539032","name":"Michael91","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"4002","last_update_time":"1653762053","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":2},{"user_id":"10998804","name":"dexter","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"5019","last_update_time":"1653761927","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":2},{"user_id":"12275790","name":"Prometeo","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"1004","last_update_time":"1653761906","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":2},{"user_id":"23080164","name":"Sandman","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"1002","last_update_time":"1653761870","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":2},{"user_id":"15711907","name":"Solo Dolo","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"5019","last_update_time":"1653761675","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":2},{"user_id":"7594613","name":"TerryL","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"5019","last_update_time":"1653761629","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":2},{"user_id":"11456091","name":"checca","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"5019","last_update_time":"1653761348","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":2},{"user_id":"23663271","name":"Vanlee","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"3003","last_update_time":"1653761296","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":2},{"user_id":"14813108","name":"chobani","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"5019","last_update_time":"1653761268","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":1},{"user_id":"10736125","name":"CoyesTwin","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"4002","last_update_time":"1653761227","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":1},{"user_id":"6347739","name":"Coye09","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"1002","last_update_time":"1653761132","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":1},{"user_id":"5829121","name":"buddhahchrst","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"5019","last_update_time":"1653761058","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":1},{"user_id":"650101","name":"David H","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"3003","last_update_time":"1653758932","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":1},{"user_id":"6018408","name":"floor88","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"5019","last_update_time":"1653758316","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":1},{"user_id":"16324663","name":"Robert","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"4001","last_update_time":"1653758106","trophy_data":[{"asset_prefab":{"asset":"badge_1000","bundle_id":"48"},"label":"897"}],"member_role":"0","online":1},{"user_id":"2448942","name":"SoloIO","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"3003","last_update_time":"1653757222","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":1},{"user_id":"72549","name":"SemmyStorm","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"5019","last_update_time":"1653754234","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":1},{"user_id":"21997624","name":"KaylaH355","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"3003","last_update_time":"1653752347","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":1},{"user_id":"9930666","name":"Giannis","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"5019","last_update_time":"1653751324","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":1},{"user_id":"10621160","name":"samelcock1987","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"4002","last_update_time":"1653750506","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":1},{"user_id":"10653806","name":"dustin","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"5016","last_update_time":"1653750272","trophy_data":[{"asset_prefab":{"asset":"badge_1000","bundle_id":"48"},"label":"272"}],"member_role":"0","online":1},{"user_id":"11818850","name":"Farabundo","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"3002","last_update_time":"1653736145","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":1},{"user_id":"20058966","name":"INeedLegs","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"5019","last_update_time":"1653717731","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":1},{"user_id":"22599854","name":"LycanBites","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"1004","last_update_time":"1653697500","trophy_data":[{"asset_prefab":{"asset":"badge_100","bundle_id":"48"},"label":"18"}],"member_role":"0","online":1},{"user_id":"20774900","name":"187ers","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"3004","last_update_time":"1653696681","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":1},{"user_id":"8075024","name":"johnboss","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"5019","last_update_time":"1653690527","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":1},{"user_id":"12927776","name":"TeamSüd","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"2001","last_update_time":"1653682045","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":1},{"user_id":"9892245","name":"Ksenia","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"5019","last_update_time":"1653676138","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":1},{"user_id":"7292419","name":"Marghh","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"5019","last_update_time":"1653664435","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":1},{"user_id":"5556550","name":"AtsukoJackson","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","commander_id":"1004","last_update_time":"1653605704","trophy_data":[],"member_role":"0","online":1}],"online_members":23,"rank":1,"invites":{"11625866":{"user_id":"11625866","name":"wenniebaby","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","trophy_data":[]},"20977031":{"user_id":"20977031","name":"stokes","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","trophy_data":[]},"22638979":{"user_id":"22638979","name":"Rincon","level":"15","pvp_rank":"16","trophy_data":[],"online":1}}}

Comment: I think this might be of help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157590/javascript-sort-custom-comparator-function-sorting-a-sorted-array

Answer (score 2):

```
const members = data.faction.members;    

// Sort the array based on the user_id
items.sort(function (first, second) {
  return first.user_id - second.user_id;
});

// prints the first 5 elements 
console.log(items.slice(0, 5));
```

That takes care of the sorting.

Here is a way to pretty print JSON using JSON.stringify. JSON.stringify accepts a third parameter which defines white-space insertion. It can be a string or a number (number of spaces). Example:

```
const data = {'hello': 'world', 'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'foo': 'bar'}

console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
```

Comment: i keep getting error C:\Users\zeKe\Documents\Banjo Bot\AT\index.js:6
const members = data.faction.members;
                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'members')
  
sorry im a newb still learning